# z-index order tile layer and json layer

Tags: leaflet, wms, json

I have wms tile layer that only show street name labels. An ajax function pulls in the street line json layer to the map. The line get drawn on top of them labels. Is there a way of controlling z-index of the json layer to be drawn under the tile layer?

I have tried .addTo(map).setZIndex(9); on my wms layer but the json layer still get drawn on top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the [Leaflet tutorial on map panes](http://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/). Panes in Leaflet 1.0.x allow exactly what you are asking for: controlling the stacking order of groups of layers.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599280/leaflet-overlay-order-points-lines-and-polygons/

Comment: Thanks I will have  a look, I am using leaflet 0.7 atm, but i will try to update it first

Comment: Thank you for the help! Updating to 1.0 and using panes did it